# How to prevent url from encoding charsets?

Tags: html, encoding, utf-8

I am currently developing rest web service. My application allow users to input a value and gets directed based on input.

User input: 10:d5
and gets redirected to localhost:8080/getInfo?id=10:d5

but in the browser url it gets reformatted because of UTF-8? and it looks like localhost:8080/getInfo?id=10%3d5.

How can I make browser url to accept 10:d5 instead of encoding it to 10%3Ad5.

Comment: It's not because of UTF-8. The colon is a [reserved character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Types_of_URI_characters) in a URL, so the browser is doing the right thing here. You should change the redirection to properly URL-encode the query string.

Comment: @lenz I can't modify it so that it would print colons on the url browser? Since it's a rest service user should be able to type an ID= 10:d5 to receive output. But instead they have to type 10%3Ad5 because of reserved word

Comment: That's what I understand. The user of a REST service isn't usually a human typing in URLs, but rather some client-side code which ideally properly url-encodes the routes.